# Can not get a connection to a mariaDB with the camel SQL component

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-sql

I always get the following exception when trying to connect to a mariDB database and i cannot figure out how to properly define the dataSource.

```
No bean could be found in the registry for: myDataSource of type: javax.sql.DataSource
```

My code is fairly simple and looks like the following:

```
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {


        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

            String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/testDB";

            BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
            ds.setUsername("user");
            ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            ds.setPassword("password");
            ds.setUrl(url);

            SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
            registry.put("myDataSource", ds);
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);


            this.setContext(context);

            //poll the mySQL Database every x minutes.
            from("timer://Timer?period=6000")

            .to("sql:select * from testDB?dataSource=myDataSource");
       }
    };
}
```

I have already tried the Blueprint version of defining the dataSource, but could not get that to run either.

Is this set up in the correct way? 
may i be missing a dependency or do i have the wrong drivers specified?

Comment: That is totally wrong, you cannot just create a new CamelContext inside Camel itself. Study the database examples that comes with Apache Camel: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples

Comment: Thanks looking at the examples has made it clear how to properly set it in JDSL as well as in the blueprint.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the examples i found out how to solve my problem.

In JDSL in CamelTestSupport the context is registered with the createCamelContext method and the dataSource is added to the context there.

```
public class IntegrationTest extends CamelTestSupport{

@Override
public CamelContext createCamelContext() {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    DataSource dataSource = setupDataSource(url);
    SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
    registry.put("myDataSource", dataSource);
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
    return context;
}

private static DataSource setupDataSource(String connectURI) {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setUsername("username");
    ds.setPassword("password");
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl(connectURI);
    return ds;
}

protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {


        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

            from("timer://Timer?period=6000")
                    .to("sql:select * from testdb.testTable
                            + " ?dataSource=myDataSource" )
                    .to("mock:result");

        }
    };
}
```

In the blueprint file a bean needs to be set/configured and then referenced by the SQL Component in the following way:

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="http:localhost:3306"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
  </bean>

 <bean id="sql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
 </bean>
```